# Как правильно писать свою СMS?

Tags: php, cms

Есть вопросы относительно написания своей CMS. Знаю примеров много и вообще такие системы не очень-то и жалуют... но вот хочется попробовать. Вопросы такие: что в теории представляют собой категории сайта неограниченной вложенности  и как они могут взаимодействовать с роутингом? Смогу я добиться таких адресов как на статических сайтах, например mysite.ru/gallery, mysite.ru/blog? Как работать с несколькими шаблонами: например главная страница имеет шаблон в 1-3 колонки, у блога вывод постов разный по дизайну, галерея тоже самое? Для разного вида форм написать генератор. Так вот логичнее его использовать и в админ панели тоже, но мне сказали что это потенциально небезопасно будет, почему? Как защитить админ панель-более надежный способ?

Answer (score 3):

Единственный правильный путь в написании своей CMS - не делать этого от слова вообще. Если у вас есть свободное время, лучше его потратить с пользой. 
Поставьте Symfony, поймите как работает. Посмотрите как пишут код, поучаствуйте в разработке, если посчитали что разобрались и сможете. Будет больше пользы для вас, поверьте.

Все задачи, которые вы для себя придумали, уже реализованы другими людьми и более верно и правильно. А чтобы развиваться, не обязательно идти по граблям.

Comment: Смотрю конечно в эту сторону и Symfony и и решение задач другими. Но я такой, что чтобы мне понять всё это нужно решить задачу самому-пусть криво и нерационально)

Comment: Попробую провести аналогию: вы, чтобы впервые забить гвоздь, молоток тоже сами изготавливать будете? Относитесь к CMS как к инструменту: на первых парах нужно изучить те, что есть. У вас явно мало опыта в разработке, для того чтобы писать осмысленную CMS. По итогу: сайт качественно и в срок не сделаете, годную CMS не разработаете, ничему хорошему не научитесь (т.к. пойдёте по своим граблям).

Comment: Опыта мало у меня... Но что даст мне Symfony? В лучшем случая я получи mySymfony))) под те задачи на которые она соориентирована. Мне кажется что вообще приложения любые разрабатывают под свои нужды. Чужой код как пища для размышления... И тогда проще и быстрее найти ответ на форуме,  а не копаться в чужом фраймворке n лет -я предполагаю. Во второй версии возможно, но не в первой. Те же книги, только на практике. Почему нет?

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов я прекрасно вас понимаю, прям вот слово в слово вы повторяете что говорит большинство, но уверяю вас, чтобы понять не нужно изобретать велосипед. Это в край ошибочное (по моему убеждению) мнение о том чтобы научится ездить на мерседесе, нужно сначала научится ездить на копейке. У Вас уникальный шанс изначально делать или пытаться делать все правильно, шанс которого у меня, в силу возраста, не было, например. Будьте уверены, у вас достаточно останется задачь чтобы "понять".

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов Symfony вам даст возможность  делать именно то что вы хотите, а когда вы наберетесь опыта, я Вас уверяю, вы пойдете и посмотрите и узнаете как работает то к чему у вас остались претензии в виде непонимании. 
Вы не думайте что Symfony решит за вас все задачи. Этот фреймворк лишь поможет решить вам стандартные задачи, а всю логику вы пишете сами.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов ну или так - представьте что через три года вы составляете резюме. 
Вы описываете свой стек как - 
1. Symfony
или 
1. CMS Joomla

Comment: Я пока об этом не думаю. Даже наоборот хочу версию 1 сделать и бесплатно скинуть на общий тестинг где-то.

Comment: К сожалению вы поймёте что ещё одна CMS кроме вас вообще никому не нужна. Тестировать её никто не будет, если конечно у вас нет никаких рычагов давления на комьюнити. Как правильно советуют люди - возьмите популярный фреймворк и напишите что-либо на нем. Потому как это в любом случае релевантный опыт для последующего трудоустройства, а не какой-то там опыт разработки только вам понятной CMS, в которой опять же - никто в здравом уме не будет разбираться.

Answer (score 2):

Есть второй путь, тоже неплохой:

1. Начните делать сайты на Wordpress, Битрикс и MODx Revo;
2. Разберитесь, какая у них архитектура, в чём их отличия, какие практики они применяют;
3. Определитесь, какая вам нравится больше;
4. Изучите её минусы;
5. Пишите модули для неё. Параллельно изучайте внутренности (ядро);
6. Если CMS открытая - участвуйте в разработке.
7. Вы великолепны:

   - теперь вы крутой специалист по популярной CMS;
   - вы начали зарабатывать ещё на пункте 1. Теперь вы зарабатываете хорошо (как крутой специалист);
   - вас не проклинают те, кто после вас ведёт сайты.

Comment: Я вас не понял) Сейчас я узнаю о том, как мне написать в теории!  А в документации фреймворка и прочем нет такого: функция  А нужна для функции B, -  а она служит для.... Там пример реализации уже. И как мне быть, читать весь код с Index.php?))) Дольше чем собрать самому (как-то) и потом совершенствовать....

Comment: `вас не проклинают те, кто после вас ведёт сайты` - не факт, если это WP или Битрикс (с MODx не работал). WP имеет неудобную для большинства нужд архитектуру, я его рассматриваю как блог и немного больше. Архитектура Битрикса также НЕ задает какие-то общие правила, там запросы ("модель") зачастую пишется в представлении ("view"), что есть неправильно. @zalex упомянул Symfony - там годная архитектура есть. А в остальном я согласен.

Comment: @TotalPusher, ну если вы проклинаете разработчика за выбор WP или Битрикса - вы промахнулись. Проклинайте разработчиков WP и Битрикса.

Пожалуйста, прекратите сравнивать WP с Symfony. CMS и Framework. ТС в посте поставил чёткую задачу: хочу писать CMS. Так то Laravel тоже имеет отличные архитектурные решения и вполне может потягаться с Symfony по удобству разработки и преимуществам. Но ни Laravel, ни Symfony не покрывают функционала CMS.

Comment: @TotalPusher, что касается перечисленных мной CMS, я ни слова не сказал об их плюсах. Я предложил изучить их минусы. На самом деле все три, как CMS, имеют и плюсы и минусы, удачные и неудачные решения. Например, Битрикс серьёзно расплачивается за гибкость и забивает на некоторые вещи. WP никак не может избавится от своего ядра и жизнеспособен только под плагинами. Но если вы отказываетесь от них в пользу фрэймворка на проекте любого масштаба, просто по сложившимся о них стереотипах - вы просто не умеете их готовить.На всех трёх CMS можно делать крутые вещи.

Comment: @TotalPusher, ну и изучить все 3 CMS просто необходимо, чтобы заранее понимать: 1. как делать не нужно; 2. какой функционал бывает в современных CMS и какие к ним выдвигаются требования; 3.какие решения удачные и удобные. И т.п.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, в отличии от zalex я не предлагаю вам изучать фрэймворк. Я предложил вам к изучению 3 самых популярных и продвинутых CMS. Любой курс по этим CMS-кам начинается с минимального описания архитектуры. Чем дольше будете работать - тем больше будете понимать, как всё устроенно. Описанный путь, при должном усердии, не займёт у вас больше года.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, представьте, что вы хотите сделать молоток. Вы берёте камень и забиваете им гвоздь. Гвоздь забит, но молоток вы делать не научились. Вы можете примотать к камню палку и соблюсти таким образом суть молотка - рычаг. Уже неплохо: у вас прародитель молотка. Но чтобы изготовить современный молоток вам всё ещё нужно знать: черчение, физику, химию, металлообработку, литьё или ковку, деревообработку и сапромат. Вы потратили пару лет, изучили вот это вот всё и изготовили молоток. Вы пробуете забить гвоздь... И по удобству ваш молоток сравним с молотком из кирпича и палки.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, я предлагаю вам взять три современных молотка разной формы и год забивать ими гвозди, постепенно изучая способ их изготовления, их фишки, сильные и слабые стороны. Через год у вас будут хотя бы примерные знания, с чего начать изучение интересующей вас области и представления об идеальном молотке, который вам нужен. Если будете делать молоток, не забив ни одного гвоздя современным молотком, рискуете пройти по всем граблям, что собирали наши предки со времён пещерных людей. =)